# How to return multiple values from a filter function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to return multiple values in typescript, implementing search filter.
If am return separately works fine, but if am trying to return both it seems not working.

Here's my code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'category' })

export class CategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(categories: any, searchText: any): any {
    if(searchText == null) return categories;

    return categories.filter(
      function(category){
       var a = category.DistrictName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
       var b = category.Population.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
       return a;
       //return [a,b];
      }
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: USe `.map` instead of `.filter`

Comment: But anyway your intention is unclear. What is the logical condition by which a `category` is included in the resulting filtered array?

Comment: For example if for a certain `category`, `a` is true and `b` is false, or vice versa, should it be included?

Comment: What is the logic of your filter ?

Comment: Attach the above snippet to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning categories.filter(categories) will return array of all the value inside categories array which match the condition mentioned in the logic. In your case, you are trying to return the boolean values. Basically, if you want to filter among the categories where district name has some search text or population has some search text then you can do something like below:

```
var searchText = 'ist2';
var categories = [
            {
    'DistrictName': 'dist1',
    'Population': 'pop1'
    },
    {
    'DistrictName':  'dist2',
    'Population': 'popist2'
    },
    {
    'DistrictName': 'dist3',
    'Population':'pop3'

    }        
  ];


  function test() {

      return categories.filter(
        function(category){
          return            
 category.DistrictName.toLowerCase().
      indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||  
 category.Population.toLowerCase()
     .indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1; 
  });

 }

  var filteredArray = test();
  console.log(filteredArray); 

  //output

   **[{
    'DistrictName':  'dist2',
    'Population': 'popist2'
   }]**
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the `Array.filter` method works: it takes a function whose first argument is the next item in the Array, performs some logic and return a value, if the value is truthy, then it will include the item in the produced array. This is used to `filter` an array, not to produce an alteration of the array. Your intention is somewhat unclear, but you most probably want to use `map` instead of `filter`